# angular-cli build, deploy chunks on a separate server

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I run 'ng build --prod' and i get 3 chunks generated, for 3 lazy loaded modules.

suppose i want to host those 3 chunks on a **different webserver** than the rest of the application. 
Is there a way in webpack to configure this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the bundled js files in a html page and host the web-page on a webserver,
for eg:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
    I'm externally loaded angular project
     </div>

 <script src="~inline.bundle.js"></script>
 <script src="~vendor.bundle.js"></script>
 <script src="~main.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when using angular-cli, you do not see in the index.html a reference to the lazy loaded module's chunks